# Track installed app from Playstore

Tags: android

My app is there in the playstore, inside my app i am promoting other app by providing the link of those app, now my question is how i can track whether the app is installed by my user using the link inside my app.

Any help or link to any related post will be appreciated.

Comment: Those other apps also developed by you?

Comment: no, those app are created by other developers, i will just promote them in my app.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try adding referrer= to the app link and try to listen for com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast receiver.